# How add window.resizeTo method in Joomla Template?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Sorry for my ignorance and I am new in Joomla but I need to open a new windows and I fixed it, added

```
target="_blank"
```

in my php script but now I would need resize this windows and I am thinking in add the Javascript metod

> "window.resizeTo"

for it, Could anybody advice me about how I should do it?

Thanks in advance

Castana

Comment: Yes. I nedd to open a new widows too..... Thanks for your help

Comment: in that case check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a popup

try this

```
window.open('YOUR_PAGE.html','PAGE_NAME','width=200,height=200');
```

and change your link from

```
<a href='YOUR_PAGE.html' target='_blank'/>PAGE_NAME</a>
```

to

```
<a href='#' onclick="window.open('YOUR_PAGE.html','PAGE_NAME','width=200,height=200'); return false;"/>PAGE_NAME</a>
```

**Edit:**

For your code, change the your

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>">
```

with

```
<a href='#' onclick="window.open('<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>','PAGE_NAME','width=200,height=200'); return false;">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Sorry again but I have to add this code to this php script.    </div>
<?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>"><?php endif; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryImage()->getSource(); ?>" alt="" class="sprocket-mosaic-image" /><?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?><span class="sprocket-mosaic-hover"></span>
<span class="sprocket-mosaic-shadow"></span>
<span class="sprocket-mosaic-hovercontent"><span>+</span></span>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div> 
For it could you say me where I should your code? Thanks

Comment: Hi zzlalani,You are right. it is works right now. Thank you so much ! Best Regards